# Testing active ssh keys on the local network

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying currently to achieve a bash script that will validate if SSH keys on a server are still linked to known hosts that are active on the local area network. You can find below the beginning of my bash script to achieve this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# LAN SSH KEYS DISCOVERY SCRIPT
# TRYING TO FIND THOSE SSH KEYS NOW

cat /etc/passwd | grep /bin/bash > bash_users
cat bash_users | cut -d ":" -f 6 > cutted.bash_users_home_dir
for bash_users in $(cat cutted.bash_users_home_dir)
do
ls -al $bash_users/.ssh/*id_* >> ssh-keys.txt
done

# DISCOVERING THE KNOWN_HOSTS NOW

for known_hosts in $(cat cutted.bash_users_home_dir)
do
cat $bash_users/.ssh/known_hosts | awk '{print $1}' | sort -u >> 
hosts_known.txt
sleep 2
done
hosts_known=$(wc -l hosts_known.txt)
echo "We have $hosts_known known hosts that could be still active via SSH 
keys"

# TIME TO TEST WHICH SSH servers are still active with the SSH keys
# AND THIS IS WHERE I AM FROZEN...
# Would love to have bash script that could
# ssh -l $users_that_have_/bin/bash -i $ssh_keys $ssh_servers
# Would also be very nice if it could save active
# SSH servers with the valid keys in output.txt in the format
# username:local-IP:/path/to/SSH_key
```

Please feel very comfortable to edit/modify the bash script above if it can serve better the goals described.

Any help would be very appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: This is confusing. [Don't use for i in cat](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor). All the temporary files are just not needed. Do you have a list of active hosts on your local network?  Or you assume all PC are turned on on your local network? Why do you limit yourself to bash users only?

Comment: Hi @KamilCuk,

I do assume that all hosts in $bash_users/.ssh/known_hosts are turned on. I shouldn't limit myself to bash users only, I should include also '/bin/sh' users.

I get your point that for i in cat is confusing with all the temp files but as long as it serves my goal I'm happy :) I am very opened to anyone who would like to edit/modify the bash script in order to make it cleaner/better.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The following works cool:

```
</etc/passwd \
grep /bin/bash | 
cut -d: -f6 | 
sudo xargs -i -- sh -c '
     [ -e "$1" ] && cat "$1"
' -- {}/.ssh/known_hosts | 
cut -d' ' -f1 | 
tr ',' '\n' | 
sed '
     /^\[/{ 
          s/\[\(.*\)\]:\(.*\)/\1 \2/; 
          t; 
     }; 
     s/$/ 22/;
' | 
sort -u |
xargs -l1 -- sh -c '
    if echo "~" | nc -q1 -w3 "$1" "$2" | grep -q "^SSH"; then 
          echo "#### SUCCESS $1 $2"; 
    else 
          echo "#### ERROR $1 $2"; 
    fi
' --
```

So:

1. Start with `/etc/passwd`
2. Filter all "bash_users" as you call them
3. Filter user home directories only `cut -d: -f6`
4. For each user home directory `sudo xargs -i --` run

   1. Check if the file .ssh/known_hosts inside the user home directory exists
   2. If it does, print it
5. Filter only hosts names
6. Multiple hosts signatures may share same key and are separated by a comma. Replace comma for newline
7. Now a sed script:

   1. If a line starts with a `[` that means it has a format of `[host]:port` and I want to replace it with `host port`
   2. If the line does not start with a `[` I add `22` to the end of the line so it's `host 22`
8. Then I `sort -u`
9. Now for each line:

   1. I get the ssh version from ssh `echo "~" | nc hostname port` returns smth like  "SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.0" + newline + "Protocol mismatch".
   2. So if the line returned by `nc hostname port` starts with `SSH` that means there is ssh running on the other side
   3. I added timeout for unresponsive hosts, but I think `nc -w timeout` option may also be used. Probably also `nc -q 1` should be specified.
10. Now the real fun is, when you add the max-procs option to the last xargs line, you can check all hosts simultaneously. On my host I have `47` unique addresses and `xargs -P30` checks them ALL in like 2 seconds.
11. But really there are some problems. The script needs root to read from all users known_hosts. But worse, the known_hosts may be hashed. It would be better to firstly know the list of hosts on your network, and then generate known_hosts from it. It would look like `ssh-keyscan -f list_of_hosts > ~/.ssh/known_hosts` or similar. Generaly `ssh-keygen -F hostname` should be used if a host exists in known_hosts, sadly there is no listing command. known_hosts file format may be found in [ssh documentation](https://manpages.debian.org/wheezy/openssh-server/authorized_keys.5.en.html).

Comment: In my experience I've used `nmap` to scan multiple hosts for multiple open ports and protocols, which is available in repos on most distros.

Comment: We could use "masscan" which is available on GitHub in order to find all the SSH servers opened on the local area network with the following syntax:
"masscan 192.168.0.0/16 -p22 -oL LAN.SSH.txt --max-rate 30000 --open --banners -sS -Pn -n --randomize-hosts -v --send-eth". This will save all SSH servers in LAN.SSH.txt. After, now that we have all LAN SSH servers listed in a txt file, how could we test them with something like: "ssh -l $users_that_have_/bin/bash -i $ssh_keys $ssh_servers" and save the positive results that can login in an output.txt ?